# What is the difference between an API and Microservice?

Tags: api, microservices

I create my API rest with Django, but I don't understand how convert an API to micro services, I don't understand the real difference between these.
I see an API like a micro service, but I don't know convert an entire API in micro service, I need create micro web servers?

Please, I can't understand a micro services, and I need understand this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A microservice exposes it's interface, what it can do, by means of an API. The API is the list of all endpoints that a microservice respond when it receives a command/query. The microservice contains the API *and* other internal+hidden things that it uses to respond to client's requests.

An API is all that the clients see when they look at the microservice, although the microservice is bigger than that. A microservice hides its internal structure, it's technology stack, it's database type (`sql`, `nosql` - it could be anything); a microservice could move from `sql` to `nosql`, from `python` to `php`, but keep it's API unchanged.

Comment: You will have a practical example?, Since I am understanding, but usually I create my web server as an API, and not a micro that contains an API and many more things.

Comment: An example of what?

Comment: Any server/microservice contains, along the API, many other things, for example de database access components.

Comment: Does my post answer your question? If yes then mark it as solution please. If no, tell me.

Answer (score 0):

**API** - It a way of exposing functionality over web. Imagine you have developed some functionality in .Net but not you are developing some software in a different language. Would you develop the same functionality again? No. So, just expose it via web service.Web services are not tied to any one operating system or programming language. For example, an application developed in Java can communicate with the one developed in C#, Android, etc., and vice versa.

**Microservice** - They are used to break a complex software into small pieces of individually deployable, testable, loosely coupled sub-modules. Micro Services are designed to cope with failure and breakdowns of large applications. Since multiple unique services are communicating together, it may happen that a particular service fails, but the overall larger applications remain unaffected by the failure of a single module.

**API Vs Microservice** - Now that we have broken our complex software into loosely couple sub-modules. These sub-modules communicate with each other via an API. Therefore, Microservices and an API solve different problems but works together!

**More Details:**

[The Difference between Web Services and Micro Services](https://www.tatvasoft.com/blog/the-difference-between-micro-services-and-web-services/)

[RESTful API vs Microservice](https://medium.com/@ericjwhuang/restful-api-vs-microservice-eea903ac3e73)

Comment: To Nitpick: An API is not necessarily a web-interface; The c-lib is used via its API, every code-library exposes and is used in terms of its API; Applications may expose an API for plugins to use etc. API is a very abstract concept

Answer (score 0):

a microservice is an autonomous RESTful service. It means, there is just one service on each server. In Spring Boot when you bootstrap your RESTful service, it will get an instance of tomcat(it's embedded tomcat) and run your service on it. So, if you have more than one service on a server, it is not a microservice, because these services are not autonomous.