# Difference between a Module & Microservice

Tags: java, module, architecture, microservices

[This abstract](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45789168/what-is-the-difference-between-an-api-and-microservice) gave the difference between a Microservice and an API as:

> A microservice exposes it's interface, what it can do, by means of an
>   API. The API is the list of all endpoints that a microservice respond
>   when it receives a command/query. The microservice contains the API
>   and other internal+hidden things that it uses to respond to client's
>   requests.

I've worked with Modules & Microservices in Java, but is there a better way to distinctively describe the differences between a Module & a Microservice?

Based on my experience several Modules were imported as part of a Microservice project. Is a Microservice a module of some kind with additional capabilities of exposing RESTful Endpoints? What distinctively differentiates a Module from a Microservice or vice-a-versa?

Is there more we can discuss about the topic in question to clarify the potential confusion?

I have added some visual aid for further clarity:

[image: An example of a microservice that utilises various modules (Source: Author)]

Please refute if you may, and also provide reliable references in relation to your experience with microservices and modules.

Comment: ImO a microservice always should be at least assumed as remote.

Comment: A microservice must act as a runnable standalone service, a module doesn't necessarily. It may just be a collection of related classes.

Comment: There are so many definitions of microservices and modules that it's hard to tell which is correct and this might even lead to heated discussion. However, two properties that _I_ feel distinguishes microservices from modules/libraries are the presence of a REST interface as well as the ability to run standalone (not necessarily useful but possible) - so anything that can run on its own (or in a container) and exposes a REST api could be considered a microservice.

Comment: @Thomas REST is needlessly specific. A microservice provides *an* API. Often it's RESTful, but that is not a requirement.

Comment: Thank you all for your contributions to this discussion. It is greatly appreciated. @Michael, If a Microservice is not often conformed to a RESTful endpoint, then how would one better describe it? Could you please help with visual aid, if possible. I used www.draw.io to illustrate the above example in the original post.

Comment: @Michael yes that's right, however I (and that means just me) would say that the API provided would have to allow for the users to be written in different technologies without the need for special wrappers, i.e. some text based format like REST.

Comment: @S34N I think I agree with the quote in your question. A microservice exposes an API. REST is just one style of API. SOAP is another. The style doesn't matter.

Comment: @Thomas, I like your comment on "different technologies without the need for special wrappers". Meaning that we can have microservices written in different languages (Java, C#, Python), and still operate altogether seamlessly, each microservice having its own RESTful Endpoints. BUT we can't expect modules to do the same. Does it make sense?

Comment: Yes, when I think of modules I tend to think of things somewhat larger than libraries but still built in the same technology (e.g. Java or at least JVM languages) - sometimes things like plugins or Wildfly's "subsystems". We're currently building a system that's partly developed as a JavaEE application and partly as a Node.js application. One could consider both parts to be "micro"-services although that's still subject to internal debate :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Microservices provides an API (REST or No Rest).

Microservice code could be written in a way that some bigger project could use it as a module.

When we choose it to be a microservice rather than module:

1. We decouple it from the system which is using it
2. This microservice can scale independently ie , use specific DB for its purpose
3. Use whatever development language (suited best for its purpose) - if using it as module then this has to be written in the language in which majority of your code bases and modules are written
4. Takes care of its data patch

Answer (score 8):

The difference between a module and a microservice is one of packaging.  Modules are programming level constructs which package and encapsulate a piece of software for reuse by other software via **inclusion** in a deployment (designed for in-process execution).  A microservice is a **deployment** of a piece of software for use by other software, separated by a wire protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Module and Micro-service are totally different terminology used in software industry. I can explain with example from eCommerce industry.

**Checkout is a module** which has features like shopping cart, order review, add to bag etc. This is more generic terminology.

**Micro-services** are more technical and they are services independent of each other.
For example, we can create 'add to bag' as Microservice. This will just add an item to shopping bag. Only the bag id and product to be added is required (most importantly). This service will not know other features like shipping method, payment method etc.