# Components Microservices

Tags: components, microservices

For a few days I'm dealing with different architecture patterns. In particular, I want to better understand the microservice architecture. I understand the basic structure, but what I haven't quite figured out is what the software components or also called "modules" stand for. I know they are software elements, but could you maybe give me some concrete examples. For example, if i have an app like whatsapp, then one of my service components would be the messaging "feature". But what i don´t understand is what the respective modules would look like.(how is that feature structured?)

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Microservice architecture is a services oriented archtecture pattern that breaks up the services based on a single responsiblity.  I usually follow the SOLID acronym when thinking about how to break this up (the S stands for single responsibility).  In your whatsapp example, the messaging feature could be a microservice with a single responsibilty. Modules, are not services, they're reusable components that can be included.  For example, I would like to have an inteface module to describe the payload of communicating with the messaging microservice. Such a module would probably include things like a message schema, auth protocols, etc.  I would use that module in my microservice, and I would probably use that module (or a similar module) in a client.  In this regard, it's not much different than a library; however, a good module will be managed in a way that I can included it as a versioned dependency.

This may be a better description: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497953/difference-between-a-module-microservice/53501900#:~:text=Modules%20are%20programming%20level%20constructs,separated%20by%20a%20wire%20protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53497953/difference-between-a-module-microservice/53501900#:%7E:text=Modules%20are%20programming%20level%20constructs,separated%20by%20a%20wire%20protocol).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But there are 2 points which i don't get. First, you say you would use your described module in a client, but how is this possible since i thought the modules are implemented in the microservice and clients are an external access. And secondly, you say that your described module would include things like message schema, auth protocols etc. But i would have thought that these things would also be modules since you need you need these things to ensure a functioning message exchange. Thank you again!

Comment: For point 1: the module lives outside the service and can be include/imported into the service.  It would probably be developed in tandem with the microservice creation.

Comment: For your 2nd point: you could have more modules for message exchange, I just like using that as an example of something included in a microservice and something you would separate out of a microservice and share (but not something that would become a microservice on its own).

Comment: I guess comparing module vs microservice:  A module is a library that scales with a service, imported like a library, and doesn't scale on its own.  A microservice scales independently and is decoupled from other services that make requests to it, also it is singular in its responsibilities (it only does one thing).